# Errno::ENOENT: No such file or directory - connect(2) for home/ubuntu/GlucoMeDDC/shared/tmp/sockets/puma.sock

Tags: ruby-on-rails, capistrano, puma, capistrano3

I am deploying my rails app using Capistrano 3, and get this error from the Puma gem:

```
bundler: failed to load command: puma (/home/ubuntu/GlucoMeDDC/shared/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/bin/puma)
Errno::ENOENT: No such file or directory - connect(2) for home/ubuntu/GlucoMeDDC/shared/tmp/sockets/puma.sock
  /home/ubuntu/GlucoMeDDC/shared/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/puma-3.11.0/lib/puma/binder.rb:367:in `initialize'
  /home/ubuntu/GlucoMeDDC/shared/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/puma-3.11.0/lib/puma/binder.rb:367:in `new'
  /home/ubuntu/GlucoMeDDC/shared/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/puma-3.11.0/lib/puma/binder.rb:367:in `add_unix_listener'
  /home/ubuntu/GlucoMeDDC/shared/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/puma-3.11.0/lib/puma/binder.rb:141:in `block in parse'
  /home/ubuntu/GlucoMeDDC/shared/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/puma-3.11.0/lib/puma/binder.rb:88:in `each'
  /home/ubuntu/GlucoMeDDC/shared/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/puma-3.11.0/lib/puma/binder.rb:88:in `parse'
  /home/ubuntu/GlucoMeDDC/shared/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/puma-3.11.0/lib/puma/runner.rb:144:in `load_and_bind'
  /home/ubuntu/GlucoMeDDC/shared/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/puma-3.11.0/lib/puma/cluster.rb:397:in `run'
  /home/ubuntu/GlucoMeDDC/shared/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/puma-3.11.0/lib/puma/launcher.rb:183:in `run'
  /home/ubuntu/GlucoMeDDC/shared/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/puma-3.11.0/lib/puma/cli.rb:77:in `run'
  /home/ubuntu/GlucoMeDDC/shared/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/puma-3.11.0/bin/puma:10:in `<top (required)>'
  /home/ubuntu/GlucoMeDDC/shared/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/bin/puma:22:in `load'
  /home/ubuntu/GlucoMeDDC/shared/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/bin/puma:22:in `<top (required)>'
puma stderr: Nothing written
```

I was looking here for an answer but none of it was helpful for me.
For example, if I do `puma:config` it will work, but using the **DEFAULT** Puma configurations, and not taken from my **puma.rb** file, even that I added conf pointing to it.

Here is my deploy.rb:

```
lock '3.10.1'

set :application, 'GlucoMeDDC'
set :repo_url, 'git@github.com:user/GlucoMeDDC.git' # Edit this to match your repository
set :branch, ENV['BRANCH'] if ENV['BRANCH']
set :user, 'ubuntu'
set :deploy_to, '/home/ubuntu/GlucoMeDDC'
set :pty, true
set :linked_files, %w{config/application.yml}
set :linked_dirs, %w{bin log tmp/pids tmp/cache tmp/sockets vendor/bundle public/system public/uploads}
set :keep_releases, 5
append :rvm_map_bins, 'puma', 'pumactl'
set :rvm_type, :user
set :rvm_ruby_version, 'ruby-2.4.1' # Edit this if you are using MRI Ruby

# set :puma_rackup, -> { File.join(current_path, 'config.ru') }
set :puma_state, "#{shared_path}/tmp/pids/puma.state"
set :puma_pid, "#{shared_path}/tmp/pids/puma.pid"
set :puma_bind, "unix://#{shared_path}/tmp/sockets/puma.sock"   #accept array for multi-bind
set :puma_conf, "#{current_path}/config/puma.rb"
set :puma_access_log, "#{shared_path}/log/puma_access.log"
set :puma_error_log, "#{shared_path}/log/puma_error.log"

namespace :puma do
  desc 'Create Directories for Puma Pids and Socket'
  task :make_dirs do
    on roles(:app) do
      execute "mkdir #{shared_path}/tmp/sockets -p"
      execute "mkdir #{shared_path}/tmp/pids -p"
    end
  end

  before :start, :make_dirs
end

namespace :deploy do

  desc 'Initial Deploy'
  task :initial do
    on roles(:app) do
      before 'deploy:restart', 'puma:start'
      invoke 'deploy'
    end
  end


desc 'Restart application'
  task :restart do
    on roles(:app), in: :sequence, wait: 5 do
      invoke! 'puma:restart'
    end
  end

  after  :finishing,    :compile_assets
  after  :finishing,    :cleanup
  after  :finishing,    :restart
end

# ps aux | grep puma    # Get puma pid
# kill -s SIGUSR2 pid   # Restart puma
# kill -s SIGTERM pid   # Stop puma
```

Any tips what else can I do?

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty sure I've encountered this before and it was a result of missing folders / bad permissions in the path raised in the error. I.E. the `tmp` and / or `sockets` folders missing or inaccessable from:

> ... home/ubuntu/GlucoMeDDC/shared/tmp/sockets/puma.sock ...

Double check these are being created as expected. It looks as if they should be, although where's `shared_path` defined - is this definitely correct?

Otherwise check permissions on folders and the file to ensure they're correct. You can run `ls -la` to check this, and adjust them as appropriate.

Hope there's something in there that helps - keen to hear your feedback.

Comment: Folders are there: drwxrwxr-x 2 ubuntu ubuntu 4096 Jan 24 11:35 pids
drwxrwxr-x 2 ubuntu ubuntu 4096 Jan 24 11:35 sockets

Comment: Also, seems like the puma.sock is there.

Comment: Argh shame - I was hoping that'd do it. There's no permission issue with writing to the `puma.sock` file by any chance?

Comment: I thing I figured out what the problem is, but I can't solve it automatically using the 'deploy.rb' bind: seems like there is missing '/' at the beginning if the path to the sock file, it should be /home/.... and not home/....

Comment: Great, glad to hear it - is this coming from your `shared_path` variable? Do you have anything you can use to reference as the project root?

Answer (score 0):

That issue may caused by wrong `puma_bind`. It should be:

```
set :puma_bind, "unix:///#{shared_path}/tmp/sockets/puma.sock"
```

Comment: Tried this, it's just ignores it and uses the default.

Comment: Have you run `puma:config`? Is that change appear in `#{shared_path}/puma.rb`?

Comment: When I run puma:config it loads the default of the gem, since I want it to use my own config file of puma. (in order to take the threads, worker and other stuff from there).

Comment: In this case, you can open your puma.rb configuration on server then change it to:
`bind 'unix:///home/ubuntu/GlucoMeDDC/shared/tmp/sockets/puma.sock'`

Answer (score 0):

As far as I tried, there is no way to configure puma in both puma.rb and deploy.rb.
So I just did all configurations in deploy.rb and it works well. Thank you all for the answers and comments.